# TypeLoadException : Could not resolve type (from typeref, class/assembly System.IO.Stream, System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, typeloadexception

TypeLoadException : Could not resolve type with token xx (from typeref, class/assembly System.IO.Stream, System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xx)

I am new with c# and Unity

I have created dll using Visual Studio using **.Net Core 3.1**

Using the dll in **Unity (using .Net 4.x)**

I can run normal code successfully. But,
While using GetResponseStream() in code of dll, I get this error in Unity.

Are the versions used in my library project and Unity project compatible?
How can I successfully use Stream reading code or in my c# project?

I am just copying dll in Unity project, do I need to copy something else too?

Comment: Are these related? https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14298 https://forum.unity.com/threads/error-could-not-load-signature-of-system-io-pipelines-buffersegment-setownedmemory.993046/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to recompile your code as a .NET Framework 4.x DLL instead of a .NET core 3.1 DLL. Unity does not support the .NET Core profile.

Technically, .NET Standard 2.0 is also supported depending on which Unity version you're targeting, but it's deprecated/removed in more recent versions.

For reference: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html

Comment: thanks @raybarrera for your answer. I am using .NET Framework now and its working
There is just one issue left. I have used static functions in my interface class. If I don't put definition in interface, it gives error as

**Method must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial**

and if I declare a body, it gives error as 

**Error CS8701: Target runtime doesn't support default interface implementation. (CS8701)**

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Which version of Unity are you on? I think C# 8 support (static interfaces) are only available as of Unity 2020.2, prior to that the max supported version was 7.3.